# Lack of vertical whitespace between math material and horizontal lines in a tabular environment

Tags: tables, spacing

Consider the table

[image]

generated by the following code:

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[]
    {\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
    \begin{tabular}{ccc} \hline
        & text        & text        \\ \hline
        text & $\dfrac{1}{x}$ & $\dfrac{1}{x}$ \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
    }
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

As you see, `\dfrac{1}{x}` is placed too tightly in the table. How can I put vertical spacing, and ensure that all texts and equations are vertically aligned in the center?

Comment: To generate the screenshot you posted, none of the four packages loaded in your sample code are actually needed. What's missing, though, is `\usepackage{amsmath}`, as it's the ?`amsmath` package that defines `\dfrac`.

Comment: @Mico Thanks, I edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can think of two distinct solutions:

- Don't use `\hline` and `\cline` and, instead, switch to the rule-drawing directives of the [booktabs](https://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) package.
- Insert typographic struts where needed. E.g., use `\mathstrut` directives in superscript and subscript positions as needed.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage{amsmath}  % for '\dfrac' macro
\usepackage{booktabs} % for '\toprule', `\midrule`, `\bottomrule`, and `\cmidrule` directives
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
    \begin{tabular}[t]{ccc} 
        \hline
        & text & text \\ \hline
        text & $\dfrac{1}{x}$ & $\dfrac{1}{x}$ \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \qquad
    \begin{tabular}[t]{ccc} \toprule
        & text & text \\ \midrule
        text & $\dfrac{1}{x}$ & $\dfrac{1}{x}$ \\ \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \qquad
    \begin{tabular}[t]{ccc} \hline
        & text & text \\ \hline
        text & $\dfrac{1^{\mathstrut}}{x}$ & $\dfrac{1}{x_{\mathstrut}}$ \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

The package `nicematrix` provides the key `cell-space-limits` to deal with that kind of problem (of course, you must use `{NiceTabular}` instead of `{tabular}`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\NiceMatrixOptions{cell-space-limits=2pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[]
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
    \begin{NiceTabular}{ccc} \hline
        & text        & text        \\ \hline
        text & $\dfrac{1}{x}$ & $\dfrac{1}{x}$ \\ \hline
    \end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

Of course, the output would probably be better without the `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}` and the tools of `booktabs`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,booktabs}

\NiceMatrixOptions{cell-space-limits=2pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[]
    \begin{NiceTabular}{ccc} \toprule
        & text        & text        \\ \midrule
        text & $\dfrac{1}{x}$ & $\dfrac{1}{x}$ \\ \bottomrule
    \end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the second code]